# Custom XML Ribbon from Project to Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-project

I have the following code that creates a custom ribbon in Project 2016. I would like to create the same ribbon in Outlook 2013. When I try to run the code in an Outlook module it throws an error at `ActiveProject.SetCustomUI (ribbonXml)`

What's the correct expression for Outlook?

```
Sub PNtab()

'v1'-----------------------------//-----------------------------
    'ACTIVA O SEPARADOR DO MÓDULO DE PRODUTOS NOVOS
    Dim ribbonXml As String

    ribbonXml = "<mso:customUI xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:ribbon>"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:tabs>"
    'Título do módulo
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:tab id=""produtos_novos"" label=""Produtos Novos"">"

    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:group id=""newProject"" label=""New Project"" autoScale=""true"">"
    'New Project
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:button id=""new"" enabled=""true"" label=""New Project"" imageMso=""SourceControlAddObjects"" size=""large"" screentip=""Novo Projeto"" supertip=""Cria novo projeto baseado no APQP disponível na documentação de suporte."" onAction=""newProjectForm"" visible=""true"" />"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:group>"

    'Rótulo do primeiro separador - New Product
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:group id=""new_product"" label=""New Product"" autoScale=""true"">"
    'Presentation Meeting
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:button id=""newProjectPN"" enabled=""true"" label=""Presentation Meeting"" imageMso=""MeetingsWorkspace"" size=""large"" screentip=""Apresentação Produto Novo"" supertip=""Cria apresentação em PowerPoint baseada nos dados inseridos em Dados do Projeto."" onAction=""newProjectPN"" visible=""true"" />"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:group>"

    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:tab>"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:tabs>"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:ribbon>"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:customUI>"


    ActiveProject.SetCustomUI (ribbonXml)
    '-----------------------------//-----------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Not sure, but I am sure that Outlook doesn't have an ActiveProject object.

Comment: @0m3r this is all. It works on Project.

Comment: @EricChristoph You're right. I'm looking for the corresponding in Outlook.